# How to use sbt eclipse plugin to put all dependencies in eclipse Library Folder ClasspathContainer?

Tags: eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator, sbteclipse

After I run `activator eclipse` command and import project into eclipse, we can see all dependencies be separated. I want to put all dependencies(jar) into a Library Folder ClasspathContainer when i run `activator eclipse`. So how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade eclipse for the latest version.